# error CS0115: 'Pong.Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to compile this code but it won't work, getting this error upon compilation:

> Pong\Form1.Designer.cs(14,33,14,40): error CS0115: 'Pong.Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;

namespace Pong
{
    public partial class gameArea : Form
    {
        PictureBox picBoxPlayer, picBoxAI, picBoxBall;
        Timer gameTime; // also the game loop

        const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
        const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

        Size sizePlayer = new Size(25, 100);
        Size sizeAI = new Size(25, 100);
        Size sizeBall = new Size(20, 20);

        const int gameTimeInterval = 1;

        const int ballStartSpeed = 2;
        const int ballIncreaseSpeedRate = 1;
        const int ballSpeedLimited = 15;

        const int aiOffSetLoops = 15;

        int ballSpeedX = ballStartSpeed;
        int ballSpeedY = ballStartSpeed;


        Random rad;
        int aiOffSet;
        int aiOffSetCounter;

        Dictionary<string, SoundPlayer> sounds;

        public gameArea()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;

            picBoxPlayer = new PictureBox();
            picBoxAI = new PictureBox();
            picBoxBall = new PictureBox();

            gameTime = new Timer();
            gameTime.Interval = gameTimeInterval;

            gameTime.Tick += new EventHandler(gameTime_Tick);

            this.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
            this.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.BackColor = Color.Black;

            picBoxPlayer.Size = sizePlayer;
            picBoxPlayer.Location = new Point(picBoxPlayer.Width / 2, ClientSize.Height / 2 - picBoxPlayer.Height / 2);
            picBoxPlayer.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            this.Controls.Add(picBoxPlayer);

            picBoxAI.Size = sizeAI;
            picBoxAI.Location = new Point(ClientSize.Width - (picBoxAI.Width + picBoxAI.Width / 2), ClientSize.Height / 2 - picBoxPlayer.Height / 2); // TODO: why picBoxPlayer and not picBoxAI?
            picBoxAI.BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.Controls.Add(picBoxAI);

            rad = new Random();
            aiOffSet = 0;
            aiOffSetCounter = 1;

            picBoxBall.Size = sizeBall;
            picBoxBall.Location = new Point(ClientSize.Width / 2 - picBoxBall.Width / 2, ClientSize.Height / 2 - picBoxBall.Height / 2);
            picBoxBall.BackColor = Color.Green;
            this.Controls.Add(picBoxBall);

            // Load Sounds
            sounds = new Dictionary<string, SoundPlayer>();
            for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
            {
                sounds.Add(String.Format(@"pong{0}", k), new SoundPlayer(String.Format(@"pong{0}.wav", k)));
            }

            // Start Game loop
            gameTime.Enabled = true;
        }

        void gameTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            picBoxBall.Location = new Point(picBoxBall.Location.X + ballSpeedX, picBoxBall.Location.Y + ballSpeedY);
            gameAreaCollosions();
            padlleCollision();
            playerMovement();
            aiMovement();
        }

        private void iaChangeOffSet()
        {
            if (aiOffSetCounter >= aiOffSetLoops)
            {
                aiOffSet = rad.Next(1, picBoxAI.Height + picBoxBall.Height);
                aiOffSetCounter = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                aiOffSetCounter++;
            }
        }

        private void gameAreaCollosions()
        {
            if (picBoxBall.Location.Y > ClientSize.Height - picBoxBall.Height || picBoxBall.Location.Y < 0)
            {
                iaChangeOffSet();
                ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
                sideCollision();
            }
            else if (picBoxBall.Location.X > ClientSize.Width)
            {
                padlleSideCollision();
                resetBall();
            }
            else if (picBoxBall.Location.X < 0)
            {
                padlleSideCollision();
                resetBall();
            }
        }
        private void resetBall()
        {
            if (ballSpeedX > 0)
                ballSpeedX = -ballStartSpeed;
            else
                ballSpeedX = ballStartSpeed;
            if (ballSpeedY > 0)
                ballSpeedY = -ballStartSpeed;
            else
                ballSpeedY = ballStartSpeed;

            aiOffSet = 0;
            picBoxBall.Location = new Point(ClientSize.Width / 2 - picBoxBall.Width / 2, ClientSize.Height / 2 - picBoxBall.Height / 2);
        }
        private void playerMovement()
        {
            if (this.PointToClient(MousePosition).Y >= picBoxPlayer.Height / 2 && this.PointToClient(MousePosition).Y <= ClientSize.Height - picBoxPlayer.Height / 2)
            {
                int playerX = picBoxPlayer.Width / 2;
                int playerY = this.PointToClient(MousePosition).Y - picBoxPlayer.Height / 2;

                picBoxPlayer.Location = new Point(playerX, playerY);
            }
        }
        private void aiMovement()
        {
            int aiX = ClientSize.Width - (picBoxAI.Width + picBoxAI.Width / 2);
            int aiY = (picBoxBall.Location.Y - picBoxAI.Height / 2) + aiOffSet;

            if (aiY < 0)
                aiY = 0;
            if (aiY > ClientSize.Height - picBoxAI.Height)
                aiY = ClientSize.Height - picBoxAI.Height;

            picBoxAI.Location = new Point(aiX, aiY);
        }
        private void padlleCollision()
        {
            if (picBoxBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picBoxAI.Bounds))
            {
                picBoxBall.Location = new Point(picBoxAI.Location.X - picBoxBall.Width, picBoxBall.Location.Y);
                ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
                aiCollision();
            }
            if (picBoxBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picBoxPlayer.Bounds))
            {
                picBoxBall.Location = new Point(picBoxPlayer.Location.X + picBoxPlayer.Width, picBoxBall.Location.Y);
                ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
                playerCollision();
            }
        }
        private void playerCollision()
        {
            sounds["pong1"].Play();
            SlowDownBall();
        }
        private void aiCollision()
        {
            sounds["pong2"].Play();
            SlowDownBall();
        }
        private void sideCollision()
        {
            sounds["pong3"].Play();

            SpeedUpBall();
        }
        private void padlleSideCollision()
        {
            sounds["pong9"].Play();
        }
        private void SpeedUpBall()
        {
            if (ballSpeedY > 0)
            {
                ballSpeedY += ballIncreaseSpeedRate;
                if (ballSpeedY >= ballSpeedLimited)
                    ballSpeedY = ballSpeedLimited;
            }
            else
            {
                ballSpeedY -= ballIncreaseSpeedRate;
                if (ballSpeedY <= -ballSpeedLimited)
                    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedLimited;
            }

            if (ballSpeedX > 0)
            {
                ballSpeedX += ballIncreaseSpeedRate;
                if (ballSpeedX >= ballSpeedLimited)
                    ballSpeedX = ballSpeedLimited;
            }
            else
            {
                ballSpeedX -= ballIncreaseSpeedRate;
                if (ballSpeedX <= -ballSpeedLimited)
                    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedLimited;
            }
        }
        private void SlowDownBall()
        {
            if (ballSpeedY > 0)
            {
                ballSpeedY -= ballIncreaseSpeedRate;
                if (ballSpeedY <= ballStartSpeed)
                    ballSpeedY = ballStartSpeed;
            }
            else
            {
                ballSpeedY += ballIncreaseSpeedRate;
                if (ballSpeedY >= -ballStartSpeed)
                    ballSpeedY = -ballStartSpeed;
            }

            if (ballSpeedX > 0)
            {
                ballSpeedX -= ballIncreaseSpeedRate;
                if (ballSpeedX <= ballStartSpeed)
                    ballSpeedX = ballStartSpeed;
            }
            else
            {
                ballSpeedX += ballIncreaseSpeedRate;
                if (ballSpeedX >= -ballStartSpeed)
                    ballSpeedX = -ballStartSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you modify the designer-generated code (Pong\Form1.Designer.cs)?

Comment: You don't seriously expect us to read all that junk do you?  remove all the code that is irrelevant.

Comment: I have noticed one thing that error says `Pong.Form1.Dispose(bool)` where the class name is `gameArea` have you modified the class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, changing the class name in the .cs file without updating other references can break things. You started with a `Form1` class, changed one of the references to `gameArea`, but not the other references. As a result, you have *two* classes, `gameArea` which derives from `Form`, and `Form1` which implicitly derives from `object`. `Form1` contains the `Dispose` method, but `object` doesn't have any `Dispose` method to override.

To fix this, first change `gameArea` back to `Form1`. That should let your code compile again. Then open the designer, and use that to rename `Form1` to `gameArea`. This will update a bit more than you manually did.

Hans Passant points out in the comments that it's also possible to use "Rename" option from the context menu (under "Refactor") instead of the designer. This will update any references in the code without going through the process of creating a design-time form and saving that. As a result, may have slightly different results from what renaming in the designer would get you, for example if your code accesses your form's `Name` property, but for most programs, it should be good enough.

Comment: You might want to mention right-click > Refactor > Rename as the way to accomplish the same from the editor.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, but testing that, it doesn't actually do the same thing. On a blank form, I immediately found differences: rename doesn't update the name and the comments in the designer file. Now those are harmless differences, the code will still work, but I'm not convinced there aren't other differences in more complex forms that do matter.

Comment: It works fine, the code serializer only cares about type names.

Comment: @HansPassant Put it in my answer, thanks. I hope I worded it in a way that doesn't unnecessarily warn the OP not to do that, but at the same time still points out the potential differences.

Comment: so I changed public partial class gameArea : Form to public partial class Form1 : Form , public gameArea() to public Form1() and partial class Form1 to partial class gameArea . I tried to compile this code but it won't work, getting this error upon compilation: error CS0115: 'Pong.gameArea.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: I changed partial class gameArea to partial class Form1 alone in the designer. It's working now

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by having deleted the code segment "InitializeComponent();" for a WinForm application i.e. the segment should come FIRST on its own.